# R and postgreSQL table operation

Tags: r, postgresql, connection

I have been working on this function that tries to obtain all of the households with at least one from LA. When I use the package data.table, it is possible to upload and run the function with good results, but due to memory problems I'm using postgreSQL and here becomes the problem.

```
    year    sample  serial  pernum  wtper   relate  birthyr bplctry
    2005    8406    1244876000  3   75  4   NA  24040
    2005    8406    1244877000  1   62  1   NA  22010
    2005    8406    1244877000  2   67  2   NA  24040
    2005    8406    1244878000  1   137 1   NA  24040
    2005    8406    1244878000  2   130 2   NA  24040
    2005    8406    1244878000  3   149 3   NA  24040

> paises
 [1] 21080 21100 21130 22020 22030 22040 22050 22060 22070 22080 
23010 23020 23030 23040 23050 23060 23100 23110 23130 23140
```

Then, the reading (works)...

> create a PostgreSQL instance and create one connection.

```
m <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(m, user="postgres", password="xxxx", dbname="IPUMS", host='localhost', port=5432)

mig_db <- src_postgres(dbname = 'IPUMS', user = 'postgres', password = 'xxxx')
```

> Then, here I tried to obtain all the households with one LA. (that part works if I read USA with fread function from data.table pckg, but here is the code for the SQL statement)

```
USA <- tbl(mig_db, sql('SELECT * FROM namerica'))

paises.n <- fread('paises.csv',header=T, sep=',', data.table=F)

paises <- paises.n$code
```

> Here is the problem, the function returns a logical vector (logical(0)) for USA$latino:

```
USA$latino <- ifelse(USA$bplctry %in% paises, 'LA', 'otro')

la <- USA[USA$latino == 'LA', ]

id <- unique(la$serial)

usa.new <- USA[USA$serial %in% id,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try using the dbGetQuery function in the RPostgreSQL library

```
dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from namerica")
```